# Как организовать правильно кеширование запросов к БД?

Tags: php, mysql, кэширование

VPS. Сайт.  Серверная часть - PHP и MySQL. Есть поиск по сайту. После ввода 2-х символов идет запрос к БД и результаты сразу выгружаются под строку поиска. При вводе более 2-х символов - поиск сделал уже на стороне клиента из того, что пришло из БД, чтобы избежать лишних запросов.

С клиентской частью все гуд, все по скорости устраивает. А вот запрос к БД не устраивает, около 2-х секунд - это долго, пользователь не будет набирать сначала два символа, потом подождал, потом остальные.

Поиск идет по разным таблицам: категории, подкатегории, товары, пользователи и т.п. Попутно, идут запросы к связанным таблицам, например страны, города и т.п., чтобы потом у пользователей, в результатах удовлетворяющих строк, подставить название страны и города, например.

Запросы стандартного вида:

`$resultCat = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,title FROM cat WHERE title LIKE '%".$query."%' ORDER BY title");`

Для связанных записей:

`$resultCityList = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,title FROM city ORDER BY title");// Вытаскиваем все города`

Затем, все это собирается в кучу и отдается AJAX-ом клиенту.

Получается, что есть записи, которые можно кешировать на месяц, какие-то на сутки, какие-то на 15 минут, какие-то минут на 5.

Как поступить лучше, посоветуйте пожалуйста:

1) Кешировать как-то весь результат всех запросов для определенного значения $query. Т.е. если учесть что пользователь будет вводить на русском языке и это 2 символа, то думаю менее 1000 возможных результатов будет.

2) Кешировать каждый запрос по отдельности с указанием срока.

Ну и самый интересный вопрос: какое кеширование лучше здесь подойдет?

Поможет ли MySQLCache, типа

`$resCity = $mysqli->query("SELECT SQL_CACHE id,id_country,title FROM city ORDER BY title");`

Или какое кеширование будет наиболее эффективным? Вообще этого не касался...
Буду безмерно благодарен за советы и помощь!

Comment: Лучше всего сделать нормальный полнотекстовый поисковый индекс, а не гулять по таблицам с LIKE.

Comment: Сейчас сделал запрос к БД при вводе 3-х символов вместо 2-х, уже намного веселее.

Comment: Полнотекстовой индекс можно было бы сделать, если бы человек ввел слово и нажал искать, я правильно понимаю? У меня задумка была немного другая: Пользователь начинает вводить запрос, страница прокручивается вверх, снизу до конца экрана появляется блок с прокруткой, в котором отображаются все варианты ответов. При вводе дополнительных символов поиск идет на JS, неудовлетворяющие поиску результаты скрываются. Даже кнопки "Искать" нет, сабмит по ентеру тоже отключил. Всё на лету тут же.

Comment: Если брать и кешировать каждый запрос из 7-и на странице, то есть смысл это делать или нет при небольшой таблице, но которая очень редко меняется? Если таблица товаров, то ее можно минут на 5 кешировать, а вот категории товаров, города, страны - смело на час можно. Это будет иметь смысл или только при запросах к большим таблицам, в которых более 30-ти полей и более 10 000 записей?

Comment: Никто не запрещает искать по полнотекстовому индексу тоже на лету. Кешировать лучше не на пять минут и не на час, а до момента следующего обновления.

Comment: Кешировать имеет смысл всё, что пагубно влияет на производительность, но это лучше делать после того, как другие способы оптимизации уже применены и всё равно не дают достаточную производительность. В вашем случае ещё явно можно попробовать поиграться с индексированием текста, если ещё не пробовали.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, что имеется ввиду под индексированием текста, как это применимо в моем случае? Если кешировать с помощью Мемкешед, как отслеживается обновление таблицы, чтобы сбросить кеш?

Comment: Про индексирование и полнотекстовый поиск много информации в интернете и без меня. Тот код, который занимается обновлением таблицы, может без проблем обратиться к мемкешду с командой сброса.

Comment: Сможете подсказать по двум моментам:

1) Если сравнивать скорость выполнения (не нагрузку на сервер) небольшой выборки из БД и складывания в массив стандартно, со скоростью выполнения подключения к Memchashed, проверкой на наличие и взятие оттуда если есть?
Т.е. если сравнить скорость выполнения запроса к БД с городами (их там 320), затем перебираем строки и складываем в массив со скоростью взятия готового массива из Мемкешед если он там есть.
Стоит или нет?

Comment: 2) Так как поиск у меня только по названиям компаний, товаров, категорий, подкатегорий, может не искать в каждой таблице при помощи %LIKE% вхождение подстроки из 3-х символов, а вытащить все названия по очереди, положить в один массив и закешировать при помощи Мемкешед. Затем, при обновлении или добавлении новой записи в БД кеш сбрасывать и перезаписывать. А поиск осуществлять перебором названий из этого массива и функцией, например stripos, смотреть, подходит ли нам строка или нет. Если подходит - оставляем и показываем пользователю, а если === false, то нет.
Это будет быстрее?